sculpt mode symmetry mirror mode not working
sculpt mode symmetry mirror mode not working,
i dont know what is going on so i summon help from designers here



The symmetry is calculated around the object's origin, so check if your model has its origin in a correct location (and sculpt in loc 000, rot 000 and scale 111, as a good habit).
If not, select a vertex on the center line of the model, press Shift+S > Cursor to Selected, then in Object Mode, right click and set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor.
Now in Sculpt Mode you can use the "Symmetrize" operator, choosing if to copy from -X to + X or vice versa.

https://prnt.sc/Ml_rYXLVcMDH help, did the  * If not, select a vertex on the center line of the model, press Shift+S > Cursor to Selected, then in Object Mode, right click and set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor. * but that is the result https://workupload.com/file/6SyVGWhVqU6 if you use simmetrize will do a horrible monster

That's because the rotation of your model is not 0,0,0. To solve select the model in obj mode, press Ctrl A > Apply Rotation, then in Edit mode Symmetrize from + X to - X. As I said in my answer, you should sculpt in Loc 000, Rot 000 and Scale 111 (use Apply operator if necessary).
